# VirtualBox Won't Respond After Killing Task

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, manjaro, hypervisor

I tried to load a Debian OS, it was trying to start the VM but it took forever. I decided to kill VirtualBox processes, now whenever I start VirtualBox it won't open, it's just on my taskbar, if I hover over it the preview is just all black. I can't even close it unless I kill it under my terminal emulator. I'm using Manjaro.

Comment: Back up any guest machines, uninstall Virtual Box, restart, install the newest version and see if that fixes Virtual Box.